# Set URL parameter in java script along with add class to div

Tags: javascript, html

I have button which have Onclick function, when the button clicked it will pass a value to the JavaScript
this value will be added to URL as parameter and if the parameter is set the JavaScript function will add class name to div tag.
The problem is:
the parameter is set successfully when button clicked but the class name cannot be added to the div tag.
here below is the button code:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-primary open" value="<?php echo $msgs['id'] ?>" onclick="myFunction(this.value)" > <i id="open" class="far fa-eye"></i></button>
```

and here below the `MyFunction()` function:

```
function myFunction(val) {
  

    window.location.href = "contact.php?open-msg=" + val;

    const activeDiv = document.querySelector('.popup-overlay');
    const activeDiv1 = document.querySelector('.popup-content');

    activeDiv.classList.add('active'); 
    activeDiv1.classList.add('active'); 

}
```

what I think is the problem is that after parameter added to URL the page refresh and the execution of  the rest of code is quit.
and I really have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the page that as been reload the JavaScript will not execute.
Try it this way:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-primary open" value="<?php echo $msgs['id'] ?>" onclick="myFunction(this.value)"> <i id="open" class="far fa-eye"></i></button>
<script>
  function myFunction(val) {

    window.history.pushState('', '', '/contact.php?open-msg=' + val);

    const activeDiv = document.querySelector('.popup-overlay');
    const activeDiv1 = document.querySelector('.popup-content');

    activeDiv.classList.add('active');
    activeDiv1.classList.add('active');

  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the page will refresh and the rest of the code won't be executed.

So you have to add the class before changing the params

So it should be

```
function myFunction(val) {

    const activeDiv = document.querySelector('.popup-overlay');
    const activeDiv1 = document.querySelector('.popup-content');

    activeDiv.classList.add('active'); 
    activeDiv1.classList.add('active'); 

    
    window.location.href = "contact.php?open-msg=" + val;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` redirects the page. You might want to use `window.history.pushState` or `window.history.replaceState`